# Is Installing Jruby on Nitrious.io possible?

Tags: nitrousio

Does Nitrous.io support JRuby?

Installing it with RVM seems to attempt to run a sudo apt-get update, which it won't allow...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to update RVM.

```
rvm get head
```

From there you can install jruby:

```
rvm install jruby
```

Next, set RVM to use jruby.

```
rvm use jruby
```

Next, add jruby to your PATH.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jruby/bin
```

From there you should be able to check that jruby is working with the following command:

```
jruby --version
```

Comment: yep, looks like upgrading RVM does it, since they changed how autolibs are handled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, installing a jruby binary seems to work fine, but still cant figure out how to get RVM to do the install...

So, I just manually moved jruby into the .rvm folder...I put a copy of the binary in the .rvm/rubies directory, made a symlink from the binaries' "jruby" executable to a "ruby" executable in the .rvm/rubies bin folder,  made related empty folders for jruby in the .rvm/gems directory for the version of jruby, and did "rvm jruby-1.7.8 do rvm gemset create" and now I can do "rvm use jruby"...things seem to work fine.

I have a bad feeling about this tho. But I always do when using RVM...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will actually require any additional packages (so this might not work), but you could try running rvm with `--autolibs=0` so it doesn't attempt to install any packages; see https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for details.